# Loading Google Map In Asyntask In Android

Tags: android, google-maps

How do I load google map in async task. My app requires that when a user clicks a dialog box, it loads a google map activity. However it takes  a lot of time for the app to load the map activity. I would like the loading of the map to be a bit faster. or possibly notify the user that google map is loading. I feel async task will be the best way to do this. But how do i achieve this through async task? Or is there a better of doing this? thank you.

Comment: Are you using a map fragment in your xml file

Comment: @krishna yes am using a map fragment in my xml.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.
 make your activity  implement  OnMapReadyCallback

```
mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map);
 //start a progress dialog here 
 mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap arg0) {
    mMap = arg0;
    //cancel the progress dialog here
}
```

Comment: your suggested code did work when i tried it.But the dark screen  and long delay is still there.

Comment: do the progress dialog comes up??